# Quo modo Latine redditur "fool proof"?

Tags: classical-latin, idiom, adjective

Quo modo expressio Anglica "fool proof" Latine reddi potest?
Nullum idioma Latinum significatione simile scio.
Eandem rem Latine exprimere possum, exempli gratia dicendo "perbene munitus", sed malim vocem (aut voces) invenire, qua utebantur iam Romani antiqui.
Ecce exemplum usus: "Hoc systema securitatis ____ est."

---

Short English version: How to translate "fool proof" into Latin? *Perbene munitus*?

Comment: Mea hoc interest rogatum, nec ullum reperire responsum possum. Neologismum proponerem ut e.g. "instultabilis, -e," non vero exstat scilicet in corpore ubique.

Comment: @JoelDerfner, nescio an inveniri possit idioma Latinum aptum ad stultitiam ullo modo attinens. In lingua Finnica expressio similis est, Anglice fere est "idiot safe" (idioottivarma), sed nolo nimis extrapolare e duobus punctis datis.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ne perderetur quomodo sensus communicetur voce anglica *foolproof*, dicerem aliquid ***et(iam) stultis idoneum*** esse. Hoc *et* vel *etiam* addo, nam mea sententia  *foolproof* recte dici potest anglice alteris verbis significare, "*even* an idiot could not mess this up, so *a fortiori* you, who are not an idiot" (*et* stultus hoc destruere nequit, itaque quanto magis ipse tu, stultus qui non es.")

Si tamen libertas aliis utendi verbis mihi esset reddenti in latinam, uterer uno ex verbis Vergilio gratis: ***fidum*** ([Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfidus1), sensus IIus rebus exanimis pertinet): certus, fidelis, incolumis, fidedignus. Hoc modo defectuum absentia magis significatur.

Si altera ex parte conaris sensum "operandi simplicitatis" aut "quomodo falli potest?" communicare, forsan uti deberes his: ***facile (usu)*** vel ***planum***, *exempli gratia*:

> satin' haec sunt tibi plana et certa! (Plaut. Pers. 2, 2, 1)

In exemplo tuo, forsitan reddendum est duobus superioribus verbis implicatis:

> Hoc systema securitatis facile fidumque est

---

Or, if you don't want to wade through the above quagmire: as my professor used to say when things got difficult in Latin: *anglice paulisper*:

If I wanted to preserve the same idea as *foolproof*, I would say something like ***et(iam) stultis idoneum***. I add the *et* or *etiam* to *stultis idoneum* because I believe *foolproof* can be glossed as "*even* an idiot could not mess this up, *a fortiori* you, who are not an idiot."

That said, if I were translating this in a case that did not require this exact idiom, I would use one of Virgil's favorite words: ***fidum*** ([Lewis & Short](http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/text?doc=Perseus%3Atext%3A1999.04.0059%3Aentry%3Dfidus1), meaning II for inanimate objects): *sure, certain, safe, trustworthy*. This emphasizes the "lack of failure" aspect of foolproof.

If, on the other hand, you are looking for the "simple to operate" or "what could go wrong?" sense, perhaps ***facile (usu)*** or ***planum***, e.g.:

> satin' haec sunt tibi plana et certa! (Plaut. Pers. 2, 2, 1)

In your example, perhaps a good translation would combine two of these suggestions:

> Hoc systema securitatis facile fidumque est

Comment: Me festinante errata permulta abundare haud dubium est, nec invitus vos ad corrigendum exoro!

Comment: Hem. Mihi illud perplacet *etiam stultis idoneum*. Quod ad systemam securitatis tamen vox "fidum" aliam significationem tenet, nempe "hæc systema a furis insuperabilis est"—id quod aliud diversum significat.

Comment: Nonne "insuperabilis"  (vel sicut dixi "absentia defectuum") in sensibus vocis "foolproof" inest?

Comment: Hmm. Rogatum, respectum, contortulius fit. Mihi vox "foolproof" duos habere sensus videtur: quod est "foolproof" vel I) et stulto tractari quit, vel II) fraudari haud potest. Systema quidem securitatis fortis non fraudari potest sed fortasse stulto tractari nequit. Clostellum tamen stulto tractari quit sed fortasse fraudari potest. @JoonasIlmavirta sensum alterum in animo habere videtur, quali in casu recte dicis, "insuperabilis" quidem inest!

Comment: @JoelDerfner Interpretor vocem "foolproof" non fraudari haud posse significare (cum "fool"=fallere) sed contra stulta _probatum esse._  Vide [etymologiam](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=&search=foolproof).